# Find a keyword in text and then print words leading up to a separate keyword

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to write a program that looks at text provided by a user, searches for a keyword, and if it finds that keyword, will print it as well as any words that follow it until it encounters a separate keyword. For example:

- Search for `"I"`, print until `"and"`
- User text: `"I like fishing and running"`
- Returns: `"I like fishing"`

I have tried to loop through an array of the user's text using `each_with_index`, but could not access the index of words ahead of the word my loop is currently on. Any attempt to access other indices returns `nil`.

```
def search()
  @text.each_with_index do |word, index|
    if word == "I"
      puts word + word[1]
    end
  end
end
```

Once I can print words of future indices, my next problem would be to print all words leading up to a key word that tells it to stop, which I imagine I could probably do with an `if` statement and `break`, but I'd be grateful for any ideas for this as well.

If you have any suggestions on how to make the above work, or any other solutions I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "The quickest of the quick brown   dogs jumped over the lazy fox"
word_include = "quick"
word_exclude = "lazy"

r = /
    \b#{word_include}\b     # match value of word_include between word boundaries 
    .*?                     # match any number of any character, lazily
    (?=\b#{word_exclude}\b) # match value of word_exclude with word breaks
                            # in positive lookahead
    /x                      # extended mode for regex def
  #=> /\bquick\b.*?(?=\blazy\b)/

str[r]
  #=>"quick brown   dogs jumped over the "
```

Note that if:

```
str = "The quick brown lazy dog jumped over the lazy fox"
```

we would obtain:

```
str[r]
  #=> "quick brown "
```

which is what we want. If however, we changed `.*?` in the regex to `.*`, making it non-lazy, we would obtain:

```
str[r]
  #=> "quick brown lazy dog jumped over the "
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an index here does not seem to be the right way.

```
_, key, post = "I like fishing and running".partition(/\bI\b/)
pre, key, _ = (key + post).partition(/\band\b/)
pre # => "I like fishing"
```

Comment: A variant: `str.split(/\band\b/).first.split(/(\bI\b)/).last(2).join #=>"I like fishing "`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If `split` is to be used, it should be used with `2` as the second parameter.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is it needed in certain circumstances or does it allow simplification?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It is for safety. In case the keyword appears in the string multiple times, `split` without the second parameter will split them all.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I either forgot `split` took an optional second argument or never knew that. I forget which.

Answer (score 0):

```
def enclosed_words(sentence, start_word, end_word)
  words = sentence.split
  return [] unless words.include?(start_word) and words.include?(end_word)

  words[words.index(start_word)...words.index(end_word)].join(' ')
end

enclosed_words('I like fishing and running', 'I', 'and') # => "I like fishing"
```

Comment: Won't this raise an error if either of the two aren't present?

Comment: @JasonMattingly, rewrote it so it won't look clustered.